# How to automatically update one input if another was changed?

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to update the value of numericInput from selectInput and vice versa. I would like for the selectInput to change to "Other" as selected when any value is manually entered in numericInput. I would also like for the numericInput to update when "A","B" or "C" is selected from select input.
I know that it's best to avoid circular references but I was wondering if this is doable.
Here's what I have so far. The numeric input flashes briefly when "A", "B" or "C" is selected but it changes back to empty and the selected value changes back to other.

```
library(shiny)

if (interactive()) {
  ui <- fluidPage(
    selectInput(
      "controller",
      NULL,
      c(
        "A" = 35000,
        "B" = 1200,
        "C" = 12231,
        "Other"
      ),selected = "Other"
    ),
    numericInput("inNumber", "Input number", 0)
  )
  
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$controller, {
      x <- input$controller
      updateNumericInput(session, "inNumber", value = x)
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$inNumber,{
        updateSelectInput(session,"controller",selected ="Other")
    })
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that there is an unexpected reset of the numeric input with @starja's solution. Here is another solution:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(
    "controller",
    NULL,
    c(
      "A" = 35000,
      "B" = 1200,
      "C" = 12231,
      "Other"
    ), selected = "Other"
  ),
  numericInput("inNumber", "Input number", 0)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  flags <- reactiveValues(a=FALSE, b=FALSE)
  
  observeEvent(input$inNumber, {
    if(flags$a) flags$a <- FALSE
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE, priority = 0)
  
  observeEvent(input$inNumber, {
    if(!flags$a && input$controller != "Other"){
      updateSelectInput(session, "controller", selected = "Other")
      flags$a <- flags$b <- TRUE
    }
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE, priority = 1)
  
  observeEvent(input$controller, {
    if(flags$b) flags$b <- FALSE
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE, priority = 0)
  
  observeEvent(input$controller, {
    if(!flags$b){
      updateNumericInput(session, "inNumber", value=input$controller)
      flags$a <- flags$b <- TRUE
    }
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE, priority = 1)
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the change from "Other" to "A/B/C" automatically triggers the second observer, but the first time it shouldn't be triggered because this is a change you want to display. You can use a flag for the first change to circumvent this problem. But it doesn't feel really nice, maybe there are better options.

```
library(shiny)

if (interactive()) {
  ui <- fluidPage(
    selectInput(
      "controller",
      NULL,
      c(
        "A" = 35000,
        "B" = 1200,
        "C" = 12231,
        "Other"
      ),selected = "Other"
    ),
    numericInput("inNumber", "Input number", 0)
  )
  
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    first_change <- FALSE
    
    observeEvent(input$controller, {
      x <- input$controller
      updateNumericInput(session, "inNumber", value = x)
      first_change <<- TRUE
      
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$inNumber,{
      if (!(input$controller == "Other" || first_change)) {
      updateSelectInput(session,"controller",selected ="Other")
      }
      first_change <<- FALSE
      
    })
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```